# schedule a dag to run after every 3 days

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I created a dag to run after every 3rd day at 3PM. I provided `2021, 5, 24` as the start date and `0 15 */3 * *` as the interval and was expecting it to trigger on  `May 28 2021 15:00:00`. But it didn't trigger at all. Am I doing something wrong ?

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'akash',
'depends_on_past': True,
'start_date': datetime(2021, 5, 24),
'retries': 1,
}

dag = DAG(dag_id='au_welcome_bonus_promotion', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, schedule_interval = '0 15 */3 * *')
```

**Dag**

[image]

Comment: Did you set your DAG to on?

Comment: yes its on , check my edits

Comment: When you run the CLI next-execution what do you see? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#next-execution

Comment: When did you deploy the dag? Also what is your time zone and timezone in which the dag is deployed?

Comment: I got the solution . It was taking UTC time zone